# How to find out which program prevents monitor going to sleep on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, display, troubleshooting, sleep, power-management

On a machine running Windows XP I have the problem that the monitor often does not enter standby/sleep mode. I guess this is caused by some program that is running, because it reliably works if I close all programs. Since I usually have many programs running, it would be time consuming to find out which one is causing it by simply closing programs one after another and in between waiting for the monitor to enter sleep mode.

Is there a way to directly find out which program/event is preventing the monitor from going to sleep/standby?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell which application prevent computer from sleeping](https://superuser.com/questions/1391339/how-to-tell-which-application-prevent-computer-from-sleeping)