# How to tell which application prevent computer from sleeping

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My XPS 13 9360 is set to sleep after 3 minutes of inactivity. However, sometimes it does not follow the 3 minutes and stays awake all the time.

How do I catch the offending app/s that prevent it from going to sleep?

On the flipside, how do I also make sure that it does NOT go to sleep when told by the application (such as QBitTorrent or Adobe Media Encoder)? It doesn't always obey the app instructions too, so this is quite frustrating for me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you run the cmd with admin privileges, and run the command `powercfg -requests`, it will show you anything that is keeping your computer awake.

Comment: To add to this `powercfg -lastwake` will display the name of the last device that woke up the computer.